# PCIe SATA controller problem in re hard drive capacity

Tags: debian, hard-disk, pci, sata

I have tried two different expansion cards in a machine running Debian 11 -

1. An older PCIe SATA controller with:
   Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9215 PCIe 2.0 x1 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s Controller (rev 11)
2. A newer PCIe SATA controller with:
   ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1164 (rev 02)

That data is copy/pasted directly from the output of lspci

I currently have both installed and have connected a 4 TB drive to each of them. In this configuration, everything works. I can mount the disks and set them up in fstab to auto-mount on boot.

My problem is that I don't want to use 4 TB hard drives. I have several drives that range from 10 TB to 18 TB (all tested and known to be good) but none of them seem to work with these two PCIe cards.

I am at a total loss. I've been reading documentation for over a week and can't find any mention of a maximum capacity for these.

I have confirmed that the larger drives are all 6 GB/s transfer speeds, which the PCIe cards claim to support. I have confirmed that when they are connected and the machine is powered on, I can touch them and feel that they are spinning.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

*****BEGIN EDIT*****

I was asked to post dmesg output. I'm not familiar with dmesg and the output was quite long. What follows is an excerpt that includes what I think the commenter was asking to see - correct me if I'm mistaken.

```
[    1.399293] ahci 0000:07:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    1.399294] ahci 0000:07:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo only pmp fbs pio slum part 
[    1.399555] scsi host28: ahci
[    1.399604] scsi host29: ahci
[    1.399650] scsi host30: ahci
[    1.399692] scsi host31: ahci
[    1.399714] ata29: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc500000 port 0xfc500100 irq 64
[    1.399717] ata30: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc500000 port 0xfc500180 irq 65
[    1.399719] ata31: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc500000 port 0xfc500200 irq 66
[    1.399721] ata32: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc500000 port 0xfc500280 irq 67
[    1.400005] ahci 0000:08:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0x33 impl SATA mode
[    1.400005] ahci 0000:08:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo only pmp fbs pio slum part 
[    1.400295] scsi host32: ahci
[    1.400334] scsi host33: ahci
[    1.400370] scsi host34: ahci
[    1.400408] scsi host35: ahci
[    1.400444] scsi host36: ahci
[    1.400483] scsi host37: ahci
[    1.400501] ata33: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc400000 port 0xfc400100 irq 80
[    1.400503] ata34: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc400000 port 0xfc400180 irq 81
[    1.400503] ata35: DUMMY
[    1.400503] ata36: DUMMY
[    1.400505] ata37: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc400000 port 0xfc400300 irq 84
[    1.400508] ata38: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfc400000 port 0xfc400380 irq 85
```

(skipping some stuff here)

```
[    7.631502] scsi 25:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST4000DM000-1F21 CC54 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.631698] scsi 28:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDGZ-11 0A85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.631856] scsi 29:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 870  1B6Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.631979] scsi 30:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDFZ-11 0A81 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.632136] scsi 31:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDFZ-11 0A81 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.632266] scsi 32:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDFZ-11 0A81 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.632423] scsi 33:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDGZ-11 0A85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.632566] scsi 36:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDGZ-11 0A85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.632705] scsi 37:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EDGZ-11 0A85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
```

*****END EDIT*****

Comment: what exactly does "none of them seem to work" entail? Do the devices show up in `lsblk`? are you getting any kernel messages in `dmesg` pointing to problems?

Comment: They don't show up in lsblk.

Comment: And `dmesg`? Please add the info to your question itself (by [*editing* it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/748327/edit)), and not just in the comments :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I added what seemed like the relevant portion of the dmesg output - did you want more?  Note that the first listed drive is a 4 TB hooked up to the PCIe card and the other 8 drives shown there are connected to the main SATA connectors on the motherboard. There's currently also 10 TB and 18 TB drives that aren't displayed.

Comment: Thanks! I take it the WD140… is the 11 TB disk you want to use? Because the good news is that it does show up!

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Sadly, no. The motherboard has a 1 TB Samsung SSD and seven 14 TB Western Digital HDD connected. That WDC WD140EDGZ-11 is one of the 14 TB drives connected to the motherboard.   The 10 TB that isn't showing is a WD 100EMAZ and the 18 TB is... I'd have to power down and disconnect some stuff to see it but it's not a WD140.